# Building HTML as String with Variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-parsing

I'm trying to declare a string in javascript that will consist of HTML and a javascript var to declare the ID.

My problem is that I keep seeing "The server tag is not well formed" OR "Is not a valid identifier"

I believe this has something to do with the string/quotation configuration but I can't seem to find a clear answer.

My Problem

```
var HTMLStr, newtbl = tbl + "Table";
HTMLStr = '<tbody id="' + newtbl + '" class="prodTbl" runat="server"><tr>';
```

This produces the following error:

```
Parser Error: '' + newtbl + '' is not a valid identifier.
```

I see that in the error it changes the quotations and I've tried switching the quotations multiple times between double and single quotes but nothing seems to be working.

Can anyone provide some insight as to how I might be able to write this HTML string and declare the ID with a javascript variable??

Thanks again for all your help!

________________________________Comment Answers/Edit________________________

Kolt Penny: So I am planning on assigning the string to a var which will then be assigned back to the DOM like such

```
$('#DOMName').html(HTMLStr);
```

I also tried changing the

---

SvenWritesCode: The value of table in this instance is the string "Salad" which was passed to the function.
Also I did change the string to the indicated

(I am using asp.net as well this string would essentially be injected as a new table row in an asp.net table and will consist of a newly constructed table itself, resulting in the following)

```
asp:table
   asp:tablerow
      asp:tablecell /
   /asp:tablerow
   asp:tablerow
      asp:tablecell
         {HTML Table injection Point}
      /asp:tablecell
   /asp:tablerow
/asp:table
```

---

Comment: I'd really suggest you not to insert HTML tags that way, and specially for tables. Use the DOM way of JavaScript. You can find everything about it in https://www.w3schools.com

Comment: What's the value of tbl? The three links of 'is not a valid identifier' point to asp.net and starting with a number or having illegal characters. The other weird thing is it doesn't look like it's evaluated the string at all.  Make the whole thing a string. Does that work? Maybe it's parsing, does `id="' + "test" + '" class...` work? I'm mostly guessing because I don't know *what* is producing that error.  What do you do with `HTMLStr`?

Comment: ^ What is the value of `tbl`? If I try it with string it works.

Comment: Oh, and the error comes up because users can't insert tbodys, they are generated automatically.

Comment: @KoltPenny "users can't insert tbodys, they are generated automatically". What? You should check the spec. Users can definitely insert/use/manipulate a `tbody` element.

Comment: @gforce301 But not like this. He's trying to insert a tbody as text. The XML parser is going to complain obviously. The right way of doing it is through DOM manipulation.

Comment: Hey guys, edited the question and tried to provide as much feedback as possible